# How to convert a string into a variable name?

Tags: lua

Basically I have something like below..
Feedback from the user is in the form of a string. "CONST_ME_NONE"

Is there any way to convert "CONST_ME_NONE" into the variable name CONST_ME_NONE?

```
local CONST_ME_NONE = 0
local CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD = 17
local CONST_ME_LOSEENERGY = 24

local effects = {CONST_ME_NONE, CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD, CONST_ME_LOSEENERGY}

local user_input = "CONST_ME_NONE"
user_input = -- do something to convert string to variable name

for i = 1, #effects do
    if effects[i] == user_input then
        -- do something
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: If these are local variables why not use a table values keyed to those strings to store the values instead?

Comment: @Nifim
I guess the answer to my question is "don't be lazy" lmao

I just really didn't want to make the table super big, since there's like 200 locals

-- but just to be clear, you mean this?

`local effects = {
"CONST_ME_NONE" = CONST_ME_NONE, 
"CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD" = CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD, 
"CONST_ME_LOSEENERGY" = CONST_ME_LOSEENERGY
}`

Comment: luther's answer is what i meant. that is to "proper" why to handle this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert a string with the name of a variable into a real variable using `load()`:

`load("return string")`

example:

`print(variable)`

eh equals to:

`print(load("return variable")())`

in your case, instead of

`if effects[i] == user_input then`

use:

`if effects[i] == load("return user_input")() then`

you can also check if the method works with print:

`print(load("return user_input")())`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/tMwG7mPb 
I tried this, but it is never finding the value when using `load(user_input)`
 if I use `load(user_input)()` I get the error `input:11: attempt to call a nil value`

Comment: @Xikini sorry i forgot the `return` xD, now it's right!

Comment: I feel like a fool, since I have no idea why it isn't working. xD I'm testing it here https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo , but `print(load("return user_input")())` is returning `nil`

Comment: @Xikini https://pastebin.com/raw/yFWsBqpQ it's working for me, try remove the `local`

Answer (score 3):

Since the names you're working with must match user input, and table keys can be strings, it will be much easier to use those names as table keys rather than variables.

```
local effects = {
  CONST_ME_NONE = 0,
  CONST_ME_DRAWBLOOD = 17,
  CONST_ME_LOSEENERGY = 24,
}

local user_input = "CONST_ME_NONE"

if effects[user_input] ~= nil then
  -- do something
end
```